# Change root directory that backslash points to in Java program

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am having issue running a Java program.

There's a line of code in a jar file that opens the FileInputStream to some file from `"/apps/somefile"` location,

however I do not have access to the root directory.

The issue is that I am unable to change the code since it is provided in a jar file, as such is there anyway to change to root directory that `"/"` points to when running the java program?

Here's the line for reference:

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/apps/somefile");
```

Answer (score 3):

The line of code you present does not do anything *directly*.  It is Java source code, and Java is ordinarily compiled to bytecode and presented in that form to the JVM.  It sounds like your jar may contain source files along with the compiled class files, which is sometimes done.  If that's the case then you can simply unpack the Java sources from the jar, modify them, recompile, and make a new jar from the results.

If you don't have source then you could try decompiling, as another answer suggests.  That's a bit nasty, but it probably would work.

Alternatively, what you actually ask is

> is there anyway to change to root directory that "/" points to when running the java program?

In fact, there may be, depending on the system on which the code is running.  You could conceivably run your program under [`chroot`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot), which has precisely that effect.  That's a distinctly non-trivial exercise, however, and if you don't have access to the root directory (though I'm not sure how you can do *anything* in that case) then you very likely do not have sufficient access to set up or use a `chroot` environment, either.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a decompiler to that jar. You can use : http://jd.benow.ca/

Then you need to change that class that have the InputStream and then compile again and make the Jar file.